# Does grouping keyword have different output in select and order by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am learning about grouping sets and the grouping function.

When used in SELECT, grouping returns whether the column participates in aggregation on that row.

Where as when used in order by, it can be used to sort the result by the column.

Does grouping keyword have different output in select and order by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does the same thing, returning `1` for the combined rows and `0` for the original rows.  The difference is that in `order by` the value is used for ordering the result set.

Comment: But doesn't it evaluate to 0 or 1 in the order by? Which usually would mean column 0 or column 1.

Comment: @variable . . . First, the use of positional arguments in the `order by` is deprecated.  Second, the positional arguments only work with *constants*, not with the value of expressions.